Connecting to dataverse from github action using Crm-Connector and workload identity federation
We are attempting to automate our dataverse deployment procedures. We regularly receive a large package created by a third party using the package deployer tool, and so we use the package deployer tool UI to deploy this. While we will be using the same tool for the automatic deployments, we are now creating a github action using the related powershell commands to run the deployment.
I am running into an issue with the authentication though; from my understanding we need to use Crm-Connector to authenticate to Dataverse in order to use the package deployment tool through the command line. Can I do this using a service principal with a federated credential? I am unable to figure out if this is compatible with the crm-connector. My gut feeling says no due to lack of search results, but figured I should ask here.
If not, what would the best course of action be? Using a normal service principal with tenant ID, client Id and secret like the code example below? I've read mentions of connection strings but the crm-connector has lacking documentation, and I don't have many examples to go.
I have tried connecting to dataverse using clientsecret authentication like this, which I have verified works:
$crmConn = Get-CrmConnection -ConnectionString "AuthType=ClientSecret;Url=${{ env.SERVER_URL }};ClientId=${{ secrets.AZURE_TENANT_ID }};ClientSecret=${{ env.CLIENT_SECRET }};RedirectUri=${{ env.REDIRECT }}"    

The issue is I don't have access to the client secret any easy way from our company github, so we would possibly have to add this as an input when running the workflow which is... less than ideal. I could get this to work if it's the only solution.
I have also tried this approach, but realized that this requires user input (due to mfa) which is not viable.

- name: Connect to power platform
  run: |
    $dataverseUrl = "https://${{env.ENVIRONMENT}}.crm.dynamics.com"
    $accessToken = & az account get-access-token --resource $dataverseUrl --tenant ${{ secrets.AZURE_TENANT_ID }} --query accessToken --output tsv

    Import-Module Microsoft.Xrm.Tooling.CrmConnector.PowerShell     
    $crmConn = Get-CrmConnection -ConnectionString "AuthType=OAuth;Url=$dataverseUrl;AccessToken=$accessToken;"    

Our github is already set up with a federated service principal, so it would be amazing if I could continue playing on this instead of creating some half-assed solution...
  - name: Azure login
      uses: azure/login@v2
      with:
        client-id: ${{ secrets.AZURE_CLIENT_ID }}
        tenant-id: ${{ secrets.AZURE_TENANT_ID }}
        allow-no-subscriptions: true

All help and guidance appreciated!
Note - I am way in over my head so apologies for any strange use of terminology, this is a new field for me :)
___ edit ____
I've attempted using oauth and fetching the access token from azure using the federated credentials, and don't get any errors with authentication anymore. However, the action hangs and runs indefinitely now. Will update when I figure this out
$dataverseUrl = "<dataverse url>"
    $accessToken = & az account get-access-token --resource $dataverseUrl --query accessToken --output tsv

    Import-Module Microsoft.Xrm.Tooling.CrmConnector.PowerShell     
    $crmConn = Get-CrmConnection -ConnectionString "AuthType=OAuth;Url=$dataverseUrl;AccessToken=$accessToken;ClientId=${{secrets.AZURE_CLIENT_ID }};RedirectUri=${{env.REDIRECT}}"    
    if($crmConn.IsReady) {
      Write-Output "Connected successfully to Dataverse"

    } else {
      Write-Output "Failed to connect to Dataverse"
      Exit 1
    }


Use OAUTH authentication, not window credentials.  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-apps/developer/data-platform/authenticate-oauth
